# Calculating "left" and "top" value from fixed positioned floating element

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, fixed

The following is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
This text is fixed in one spot
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test{
    border:1px solid black;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 8px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    z-Index: 4;
}
```

So far I am able to make a box in a fixed position and have it display properly (height 200 pixels and width 50 percent of the screen). The width changes when the screen width changes, but the problem I have is that I want to calculate the top-left pixel position of the box because I don't want any part of the box to appear on top of any adsense ad unit. I have my ad units on the left-side of the screen.

I tried in javascript by obtaining values of the left-most pixel of the box like this:

```
<script>
alert(document.getElementById('test').left);
alert(document.getElementById('test').style.left);
</script>
```

And I did not get a number from either message box. All I got was a blank and "undefined".

Is there a way the top-left pixel position of the box can be calculated without forcing a value on regular intervals through a javascript timer?

And no, I don't want to use Jquery.

Comment: Why not just get the height of the ad and the position the box below that height?

Comment: I want the box to stay at the bottom-right regardless of how far down the page the user is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) and [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) methods.

```js
alert(document.getElementById('test').offsetLeft);
alert(document.getElementById('test').offsetTop);
```

```css
#test{
    border:1px solid black;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 8px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    z-Index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
This text is fixed in one spot
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work here. I'm going to hope it works for all browsers.